# How to execute a command in an iframe of a popup

Tags: javascript, node.js, iframe, popup, puppeteer

I'm trying to bypass a captcha on a website and for that I need to execute a command in an iframe of a popup and i cannot find a way to do that. Here is my code:

```
const cookie = {
    name: 'login_email',
    value: 'example@domain.com',
    domain: '.paypal.com',
    url: 'https://www.paypal.com/',
    path: '/',
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true
}

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, defaultViewport: null });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setCookie(cookie)
    await page.goto('https://www.paypal-dobijeni.cz/');
    await page.waitForSelector('#login');
    await page.click('#login');
    const newPagePromise = new Promise(x => page.once('popup', x));
    const popup = await newPagePromise;
    await popup.waitForSelector('#password');
    await popup.type('#password', 'examplepassword');
    await popup.click('#btnLogin');
    await popup.waitForSelector('form[name="challenge"]');
})();
```

The command that I need to execute is `verifyCallback('<g-recaptcha-response>')`

UPDATE: That's how I do it in the console:
[First i select the iframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjzTE.png)

[Then I execute the command with the g-recaptcha-response I get from my captcha solving service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEksT.png)

Answer (score 1):

This isnt really the solution you are looking for but I'll post it in case you decide you want to use it.
First I use [argv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/argv) to parse arguments passed to the script. One of these arguments the user can pass is headless.

When the script runs, I find someway to detect when captchas pop up, and if one is detected and the browser is headless, I log something close to "Captcha appearred, run script with headless set to false and solve the captcha".

When the script is executed with headless set to false and captcha is detected, I await a Promise that holds a one second interval, which checks to see if the captcha has left the page. With the browser no longer being headless, you can manually solve the captcha. When the captcha is gone, the interval is cleared and the Promise is resolved and the rest of the script will execute.

If you are lucky, the captcha won't need to be solved again for that ip address